# Convert videos to ZUNE - with menus, subtitles, etc intact

Tags: video, conversion, zune, zune-hd

Title says it all...I'm looking for a video converter that will convert videos to the Zune format, with subtitles and menus intact...in other words, I want to be able to play the video, and interact with the menu, etc...Is this possible?  Any recommendations/suggestions?

All models of Zune...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer [Handbreak.fr](http://Handbreak.fr) to mediacoder. I find it much easier to use. and all you have to do is use the iphone preset and then go and turn on CC

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to a DVD along with the menus and subs - no there are none. Not even the iPhone or Android has this functionality - and I am referring to the DVD menu porting specifically.

You can however, hardcode subs into a Zune-compatible WMV format. Try MediaCoder or Handbrake with a Zune-compatible profile.

Comment: OK. so how do I do it with MediaCoder?

Comment: If you want to hard-code a subtitle into your video, you can do that by going to the Subtitle tab. Just browse for the .srt that you want to add to your video.